# Determination of the length of one of the longest palindromes in a string

Tags: c, dynamic-programming, palindrome, coding-efficiency

I have to implement a function that determines the length of one of the longest palindromes in a string. The strings consist only of numbers and letters. When testing palindromes, upper and lower case should be taken into account.

Here is my code, but it should be more efficient:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int length_longest_palindrome(char str[]) {
    int length = strlen(str);
    int longest_palindrome = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int x = i; x < length; x++) {
            int sign = 1;
            for (int s = 0; s < (x - i + 1) / 2; s++) {
                if (str[i + s] != str[x - s]) sign = 0;
            }
            if (sign && (x - i + 1) > longest_palindrome) {
                longest_palindrome = x - i + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return longest_palindrome; 
} 

int main(void) {
    
    printf("%d\n", length_longest_palindrome("öaslkdhfwefjkvneifnkldnlbnlkvsdfnslkdvnaljfslfjsofnslkdfnsfjlskdnvln"));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would be really grateful for an additional explanation of your suggestions/code on how it would be  more efficient (A friend suggested to me to test the biggest Part-strings, but we did not get any further there).

Comment: **It's your lucky day.** I have a C++ solution that you can adapt back to C that runs in O(N) time in the average case. Funny thing - this came out of a friendly discussion with co-workers over the weekend when we were chatting about coding problems on Friday.  https://github.com/jselbie/find_longest_palindrome/blob/main/palindrome.cpp  Pretty much all you have to do is replace `string` with a struct that holds the `char*` and `size` value. Don't call strlen more than once in your code if you can help it, otherwise, it will degrade back to O(N²).

Comment: have you heard about Manacher's Algorithm? It solves this problem in O(N). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring#Manacher's_algorithm

Comment: Also, low hanging fruit: pass the size as parameter. Use const correctness.